# Jquery Validator Plugin - Check Multiple Fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form which has multiple select boxes for ski tuition, all of which default to 0. I want the form to fail validation if ALL the select boxes are 0 when the user submits the form. I may have missed something obvious, but I am struggling to find a way to work this.

```
<table class="meetandgreet">
          <form id="tuition">
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">1:1 Tuition @ &pound;40 per hour</td>
            <td class="col2">
              <select name="one2one">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>      
                <option value="2">2</option>      
                <option value="3">3</option>      
                <option value="4">4</option>      
                <option value="5">5</option>      
                <option value="6">6</option>  
                <option value="7">7</option>  
                <option value="8">8</option>  
                <option value="9">9</option>
                                        </select>
            </td>
            <td class="col3">&pound;0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">1:2 Tuition @ &pound;55 per hour</td>
            <td class="col2">
              <select name="two2one">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>          
                <option value="2">2</option>      
                <option value="3">3</option>  
                <option value="4">4</option>  
                <option value="5">5</option>  
                <option value="6">6</option>      
                <option value="7">7</option>      
                <option value="8">8</option>      
                <option value="9">9</option>
                                        </select>
            </td>
            <td class="col3">&pound;0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">1:3 Tuition @ &pound;63 per hour</td>
            <td class="col2">
              <select name="three2one">
                <option value="0">0</option>  
                <option value="1">1</option>          
                <option value="2">2</option>          
                <option value="3">3</option>          
                <option value="4">4</option>      
                <option value="5">5</option>      
                <option value="6">6</option>  
                <option value="7">7</option>  
                <option value="8">8</option>  
                <option value="9">9</option>
                                        </select>
            </td>
            <td class="col3">&pound;0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">1:4 Tuition @ &pound;70 per hour</td>
            <td class="col2">
              <select name="four2one">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>      
                <option value="2">2</option>  
                <option value="3">3</option>  
                <option value="4">4</option>  
                <option value="5">5</option>      
                <option value="6">6</option>      
                <option value="7">7</option>      
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                                        </select>
            </td>
            <td class="col3">&pound;0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">Full Day (5 hours, up to 4 people) @ &pound;250</td>
            <td class="col2">
              <select name="fullday">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>      
                <option value="2">2</option>  
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>  
                <option value="5">5</option>  
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>      
                <option value="8">8</option>  
                <option value="9">9</option>
                                        </select>
            </td>
            <td class="col3">&pound;0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">Full Week (5 hours x 5 days, up to 4 people) @ &pound;999</td>
            <td class="col2">
              <select name="fullweek">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>      
                <option value="2">2</option> 
                <option value="3">3</option>  
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>  
                <option value="6">6</option>  
                <option value="7">7</option>  
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                                        </select>
            </td>
            <td class="col3">&pound;0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="col2">Total:</td>
            <td class="col3">£<span>0</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="image" src="../Images/Buttons/adults_94x25_add_extras.png" style="margin-top:10px;" /></td>
          </tr>
          </form>
        </table>
```

I am using the jquery validator plugin, which I have used fine on many other forms, but in all of those cases I have been validating a field at a time, and never had a situation where the validation of one field is dependent on the value of others.

So, to summarise, the form needs to be invalid if all fields have a value of 0.

Thanks!

PS   I've not included the jquery code as there's nothing really to show apart from the standard validator stuff

Comment: it will be easier if you share generated html

Comment: Quote: _"PS I've not included the jquery code as there's nothing really to show apart from the standard validator stuff"_ ~ We won't just assume your "standard validator stuff" is automatically correct, so show the `.validate()` code anyway... this question will be more helpful to others that way.   Besides, you said you can't get this to work... if you don't show your JavaScript, how are we supposed to know what you've already tried, and that you're not making any mistakes?

Comment: @Sparky, fair points and I apologise if by omitting this is not clear. What I meant was that I have the basic framework of the validator working, but I have not got a rule set for this scenario, so all I would have to show would be a pretty standard layout of the validator, but without any rules set, which I didn't think was worth including.

Comment: @Robertomac, then I'm assuming that you only have `('#tuition').validate()`.  However, maybe you don't... or maybe you do, but some other reader less experienced than myself might be left wondering.  Please include it as it just makes the Q & A more complete.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom rule using the `.addMethod()` method.

```
$.validator.addMethod("myRule", function(value, element) {
    // your validation function
    // return true for passed validation
    // return false for failed validation
}, "This is the error message");

$('#myform').validate({
    // rules, options & callbacks,
    rules: {
        myFieldName: {
            myRule: true
        }
    }
});
```

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

**Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/as22v/

---

**IMPORTANT:**

You also have invalid HTML which is totally breaking your form.  You have `<form>` tags as direct children of `<table>` tags.  You can only have certain tags like `<tr>` as direct descendants of `<table>`.  As a result of this mistake, your form always passes jQuery Validation no matter how many form errors.

You must move your `<form>` tags outside of the `<table>` like so...

```
<form id="tuition">
     <table class="meetandgreet">
     ...
     </table>
</form>
```

---

**Alternative solution:**

If you can make your first `<option>` item have `value=''` instead of `value="0"`, you can use the `require_from_group` method included in [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).   With this method, you can specify that at least one `<select>` from your group (designated by `class`) be filled out.

**HTML snippet**:

```
<select name="one2one" class="selectgroup">
    <option value="">0</option>
    ...
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#tuition').validate({
        rules: {
            one2one: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.selectgroup']
            },
            two2one: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.selectgroup']
            },
            three2one: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.selectgroup']
            }
        },
        groups: { // group error messages into one
            myGroup: "one2one two2one three2one"
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/NNtAC/

Comment: thanks for your help. The require_from_group was the chosen option and is working like a dream.

Comment: By the way, for anyone else reading this, a momentary lapse in concentration with my html caused a lot of wasted time on this, so take careful note of Sparky's really helpful comment above regarding this. I'm sure most people won't make this mistake, but just in case...

Comment: @Robertomac, you're welcome.  Since you chose the `require_from_group` method, I edited my answer to include the code and demo.

Answer (score 0):

You should to have **a default selected option in each select elements**, after that you can attach an event handler on submit form event and check every elements,then if all of your select values is zero, prevent form to sumbit,so jQuery code looks like:

```
var form=$('#tuition');
form.on('submit',function(e){
    var one2one=$('select[name="one2one"]').val(),
        two2one=$('select[name="two2one"]').val(),
        three2one=$('select[name="three2one"]').val(),
        four2one=$('select[name="four2one"]').val(),
        fullday=$('select[name="fullday"]').val(),
        fullweek=$('select[name="fullweek"]').val();
    if(!(two2one || three2one || four2one || fullday || fullweek)) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Here the form is not valid!
    }
    //Here the form is valid, do anything here...
   });
});
```

**UPDATE:** For using jQuery `validate()` plugin your code looks like:

```
$("#tuition").validate({
    rules: {
        one2one: {
            required: true,
            min: '1' // minimum value of your one2one select element...
        },
        two2one: {
            required: true,
            min: '1' //the same as above...
        },
        three2one: {
            required: true,
            min: '1' //the same as above...
        },
        four2one: {
            required: true,
            min: '1' //the same as above...
        },
        fullday: {
            required: true,
            min: '1' //the same as above...
        },
        fullweek: {
            required: true,
            min: '1' //the same as above...
        },
    messages: {
        one2one: "This field must be at at least 1",
        two2one: "This field must be at at least 1",
        three2one: "This field must be at at least 1",
        four2one: "This field must be at at least 1",
        fullday: "This field must be at at least 1",
        fullweek: "This field must be at at least 1"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
    }
  });
```

NOTE: *don't forget* **You should to have a default selected option in each select elements.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I'm using the validator plugin so need a solution that will work with that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've not tried it, but looking at that, does that not mean that each and every field needs to be at least 1? If so, it's not quite what I am after. I need the form to have at least one field with a value greater than 0. So of the six fields, five can be 0, but I need one to have a value greater than 0.